# React native Expo touches not registering with EAS

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas

I'm currently developing an app using React Native and Expo, I have been developing using Expo Go. The app was working as expected so I created a development build from the code using EAS, the build was for Android. Here is the StackNavigator for the login / registration section of the app, I have removed the core functionality of the app whilst I resolve this issue. I encounter a similar bug if I hardcode the app to progress straight to it's core functionality.

```
// in App.js

// if (!loggedIn) {
    return (
     <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Landing">
            <Stack.Screen name="Landing" component={LandingScreen} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} options={
              {headerTitle: '',
              headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: theme.PRIMARY_BACKGROUND,
                elevation: 0,
                shadowOpacity: 0,
              },
              headerBackTitleVisible: false, 
              headerTintColor: theme.LIGHT_TEXT,
              }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen}  options={
              {headerTitle: '',
              headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: theme.PRIMARY_BACKGROUND,
                elevation: 0,
                shadowOpacity: 0,
              },
              headerTitleStyle: {
                fontFamily: 'SanFrancisco'
              },
              headerBackTitleVisible: false, 
              headerTintColor: theme.LIGHT_TEXT,
              }}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
     </GestureHandlerRootView>      
    );
  // }
```

The app isn't processing screen touches correctly, except on whatever component I have as the initial route. On any other components in the StackNavigator, when I click on a touchable object (TouchableOpacity / TextInput ) the onPress() function will not run or the input keyboard does not appear. However when I set any of the screens as an initialRoute that particular screen performs with full functionality, I am able to navigate to the other screens but when I navigate to any other screen the touchable objects do not perform any functionality. The app is clearly registering my touches as whenever I click on a touchable object it is briefly highlighted.

I have previously managed to build an app using EAS for android and not encountered this issue, when I built this app I got an error that I need to include react-native-gesture-handler, this is not an issue I had last time so I imagine the issue lies with that. Here is the relevant line in my package-lock.json : `"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",` for navigation I am using: `"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",`

I am unable to find any reference to issues like this online, I have found people with issues relating to react-native-gesture-handler which has been fixed by including `import 'react-native-gesture-handler';` as the first line in their top level component, and ensuring they wrap their NavigationContainer with a `<GestureHandlerRootView>` , I have tried both of these and neither have solved my issue, as well as rebuilding after implementing these changes.

For reference, I do not get any error messages or warnings from Expo and this is the version of expo defined in my package-lock.json : `"expo": "~49.0.8",`.

Thank you very much.

**Update**

I built up a working minimal reproduction in a separate Expo project and copied components over one by one to see what brakes it - nothing broke. All package versions between the two projects are identical and I copied components over directly. As far as I can tell there is no difference between the two projects except one works and the other doesn't. Just thought I'd post my 'fix' here incase anyone else ran into the same issue.

Comment: I have run into a situation a few times where some other "invisible" item was on screen taking inputs and not allowing them to pass back to other controls below it.  I found that out by using the Dev Tools to look at the React components that were on screen.

Comment: Thanks - I had a go with dev tools and don't think anything is blocking it. I'm able to press and hold on the text inputs to paste text in, and this value updates and is reflected in the dev tools screen. It just seems to be tapping that's the issue. I should add I'm also able to swipe between screens, leading me to think this is a gestures issue.